# How to target direct child selector of parent element

Tags: html, css, sass

How do I target direct child `h2` of `div` but at the same time make sure any other `h2` doesn't get changed.

At one place I have this markup.

```
<div class="cms-page-view">
  <div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>    <!-- Target this -->
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And at another place, I have this markup.

```
<div class="cms-page-view">
  <div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <section>
          <div>
           <h2>Hola</h2> <!-- Make sure this does not change -->
           <p>Some Text</p>
          </div>  
        </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this without using `:first-child` or `:nth-child()`.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
.cms-page-view {
  & .column {
    & div {
      & > h2 {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would try to avoid deeply nested selectors like in your example.  I would instead give either the parent div, or the `h1` a unique class.  It will ultimately make application of styles easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't touch your HTML, you can use `>` multiple times to achieve the result you want

**SNIPPET**

```css
.cms-page-view .column > div > h2 {
  background: red
}

/* SASS

.cms-page-view {
  & .column {
    & > div {
      & > h2 {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  }
}

*/
```

```html
<div class="cms-page-view">
  <div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <!-- Target this -->
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cms-page-view">
  <div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <section>
        <div>
          <!-- Make sure this does not change -->
          <h2>Hola</h2>
          <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```